# S3 Signed URL and multipart upload

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, jets3t

I am accessing S3 using signed URLs and Jets3t library. I have built a cipherStream over inputstream so that encryption also happens on the fly during upload.

Can I use multipart upload feature where file is divided into multiple parts and uploaded to S3 in parallel.

Does Jets3t provide any support to handle such case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multi-threaded [ThreadedS3Service](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/multi/s3/ThreadedS3Service.html) class as your service object. It has a method [multipartStartUploads](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/multi/s3/ThreadedS3Service.html#multipartStartUploads%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.List%29)(java.lang.String bucketName, java.util.List objects) that does exactly what I think you are asking for.